# Whats the best practice method for automatically backing up a vmware workstation windows server with sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, vmware

I have a dev machine running on VM ware workstation.It is on my local host machine and running windows server 2012 with SP 2013 single server farm.

I want to be able to automatically create backups of the full VMware file on an external hard drive every couple days. But need help with how to do it.

Should I need to turn off the server before copying, or can I do it while its on? Is there a code I can run to interact with VM ware workstation to turn off and turn off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Should I need to turn off the server before copying, or can I do it while its on ?**

Yes you should ensure that your virtual machine is in a powered off or suspended state,

**To back up the virtual machine manually:**

- Ensure your virtual machine is in a powered off state.
- Locate the virtual machine folder.
- Right-click the virtual machine folder and click Copy.
- Navigate to the folder in which you want to store the backup, right-click anywhere within the folder, and click Paste.

**Is there a code I can run to interact with VM ware workstation to turn off and turn off?**

To do it automatically via script : you should use `VMRUN` command that located as shown below

[image]

**Steps :** (`you should replace the paths based on your environment`)

- Creating a backup script  windows cmd file, for example, create a VMBackup.cmd file and enter: (Note : we consider that the VM is Running)

> ```
> :: Suspend VM 
> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" suspend   "F:\YourVMs\YourVMInstance\Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition.vmx"
>
> :: ROBOCOPY (or xcopy) the files somewhere, pref a different box or network drive, for example         
> Robocopy.exe F:\YourVMs\YourVMInstance\G:\externaldrive\backuparea\VMBackups\ /e /np /eta /r:1 /w:1/log:F:\VMScheduledBackups\Logs\YourVMInstance-BackupLog.txt
>
> :: restart the VM  
> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" start "F:\YourVMs\YourVMInstance\Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition.vmx"
> ```

You can now schedule this cmd file to run as a `windows scheduled task` in the normal way.

**Note :**

we consider that the VM is Running if it's not running add the following command before suspending command

```
"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" start "F:\YourVMs\YourVMInstance\Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition.vmx"
```

For more details check [Backing up VMware Workstation VMs](http://daveclarkesblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/backing-up-vmware-workstation-vms.html)